# Express-session: first user session overwritten by second user session

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

This is a get request where the user is passed to the view

```
app.get('/blog/:id', function(req, res) {
  // Define which page
  res.render('blog', {
    user: req.user,
});
});
```

This is a textarea where all of the users on this page should have their names stored.

```
<textarea readonly id="usersInRoom" placeholder="<%= user.username %>"></textarea>
```

This successfully sets the correct username as the placeholder. If a second user renders the same view and visits this page at the same time as the first user, the second user's username will be the only placeholder. How would one store the first username so that when the second user opens the page, the placeholder can be a concatenation of the first username + the second username? The data stored in any embedded javascript arrays etc. by the first user are not available to the second user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I did in fact have express-sessions persisting my login sessions. The first session was overwritten by a second user who logged in while the first user was online, which replaced the first user's credentials with the second users, and now I had user 2 online in two different browsers.

Although I tried this on different browsers, from different devices, **the problem was that the node app was hosted locally at localhost**. When I uploaded the app to heroku and accessed it from there, the user session was not overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SignalR, then you could broadcast the current list of users to each connection and update the view like in the [sample chat application](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr).

If you are using regular ajax server polling, set a client method on an interval that gets a list of current page users from a database store. Because of http's lack of state, you would have to 'retire' users from the list if they haven't posted in awhile.

Client code:

```
setInterval(checkServer,5000);
function checkServer(){
    //some ajax call to the server here 
    //that returns your user list
    ...
    success:function(result){
       $('#usersInRoom').val(result);
    }
}
```

Server code (assuming you are saving all your current page users in a table
with a field called LastModified):

CurrentPageUser class (store this in your DbContext as the CurrentPageUsers table):

```
public class CurrentPageUser{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public DateTime LastModified {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Controller method:

```
public string GetCurrentUsers(int selfid){
    using (var db=new DbContext()){
       var now=DateTime.Now;
       //update your requesting user so other users can see him/her
       db.CurrentPageUsers.Find(selfid).LastModified=now;
       db.SaveChanges();
       DateTime timelimit = now.AddMinutes-5);
       return string.Join(", ",
         db.CurrentPageUsers.Where(u=>
            u.LastModified<timelimit).Select(u=>u.Name).ToList());
    }
}
```

Note that the SignalR implementation has much better performance and is less clumsy to implement on the server side with no need for a database table to store the current page users. It was made for this type of scenario.